# How to replace characters?

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have numeric data such as 8,1, 9,2 etc. and I need to use this data on Weka Data Mining program. So I need to replace commas with dots (8,1 --> 8.1). I have selected data and replaced with dots(Ctrl + H) but the values is changed irrelevantly (8,1 --> 41647,0). What is the problem here? How can I change commas with dots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Find/Replace dialog will convert the values to numeric values if possible, and that means that it will also try to convert to dates, since dates are numeric values, only differently formatted. And it seems that your Excel is interpreting the `.` as a date delimiter.

A workaround for keeping the value as text would be to use `SUBSTITUTE`, but that means that you will have to use a column to do this, then copy paste the results as values.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1, ",", ".")
```

If the value is in cell `A1`.